# Integration of $x\sec^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

In the integration by-parts of $ x\sec^{-1}(x)$, since $\sec^{-1}(x) = \cos(x)$, why can't we just rewrite it as $x\cos(x) $ then integrate?

Comment: How do you know that $\sec^{-1}x=\cos x$

Comment: Do you means the arcsecant function or the reciprocal secant function? This is a notational problem in math. If it is the reciprocal secant function, then that is the cosine function.

Comment: Does $\sec^{-1} x$ denote the reciprocal of $\sec x$ or its inverse function?

Comment: If we write $\sec^{-1} x$ it is the inverse of $\sec x$. If you want to write the reciprocal of $\sec x$, then you have to use $(\sec x)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I get what the issue is now.

Comment: Wow, my most popular comment! Also, this question resurfaced.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that $\sec^{-1}$ means the *functional* inverse of $\sec$: if we restrict the domain of $\sec$ to $[0,\pi]\setminus\{\pi/2\}$, then $\sec^{-1}$ can be defined as the function such that for all $x\in\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}\dom(\sec)$,
$$
\sec^{-1}(\sec x)=x
$$
and for all $x\in\dom(\sec^{-1})$,
$$
\sec(\sec^{-1}(x))=x \, .
$$
The function $\sec^{-1}$ is different to $(\sec)^{-1}$, which is the *multiplicative* inverse of $\sec$: there are numbers $a$ such that
$$
\sec^{-1}(a)\neq(\sec a)^{-1}
$$
Take, for instance, $a=1$. Moreover, the domain of $\sec^{-1}$ is different to that of $(\sec)^{-1}$.

Comment: What would the integral be, in the title?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: I made the substitution $u=\sec^{-1}(x)$, and then integrated by parts, to get that$$\int x\sec^{-1} x \, dx = \frac{x^2\sec^{-1}x - \tan(\sec^{-1} x)}{2}+C$$We can also write $\tan(\sec^{-1}x)$ as $x\sqrt{1-1/x^2}$, if you consider that to be simpler.